# AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'Dataset' when trying to import my class

Tags: python, refactoring, python-import, dry, code-organization

I have namedtuples that I currently defined multiple times in the same way in different files because the interface is defined that way. As it is good practice I would like to have them in a central place.

How can I reference these declarations from a different file? They are defined in a file called `types.py`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Dataset = namedtuple('Dataset', ['x', 'y', 'seq_lengths'])
```

I assumed they could be referenced like `types.Dataset` in a different file, but it does not work.

**Update:** I was importing the built-in `types` module, which did not have my declaration.  **I changed the module name and now it works**. Thanks for Wondercricket's comment.

Comment: *But it does not work*. Can you explain what's not working? Are you getting errors? Perhaps you are getting conflicts with the built in module [types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), which is happening to me

Comment: Oh, you are right. That was my mistake. Thanks a  lot!

Comment: @vaultah I disagree. Yes, the question is quite difficult to discover, but it's still a useful (and not uncommon) question. Editing the title into shape could work wonders for its discoverability.

Comment: @vaultah Hmm, not quite sure why "inverse". Looks like a suitable duplicate to me.

Comment: Looks fine to me too.  Upvoted and closed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey the difference is who shadows who.  In the target, user code is shadowing the library code.  In this one, library code is shadowing user code.

Comment: @wim Oh, right. (*facepalm*) Still works as a duplicate though. The root cause is the same, after all.

Comment: @wim Do you think the new title makes sense? I would have never searched for "types" or "Dataset" since these were names given by me.

Comment: Yes.  Other users could easily get the same problem by using the name "types".    Though the name "Dataset" is unlikely to be reproduced, the search is fuzzy enough to find approximate matches and having a placeholder there is also helpful for context.